# Select and wrap string in text

Tags: jquery, html, twitter

I have tweets being generated through the Twitter API, for example:

```
<article class="tweet">
    Some users may have experienced issues accessing http://t.co/zDdcbPNfnU on @Firefox 22+. We've reached out to Mozilla and it's now resolved.
</article>
<article class="tweet">
  The issue with viewing photos is now resolved. Thanks for your patience!
</article>
```

The links aren't generating with the correct markup, so now what I want to do is select any words that begin with `http://` and wrap those words in an anchor tag.

I thought I could do something similar to this, but this obviously doesn't work:

```
$('article.tweet').each(function(){
  var linkHref = $(this).html().find('http://');
  $(linkHref).wrap('<a href="' + linkHref + '" />');
});
```

How can I select the links with jQuery?

Comment: What you are doing is the method I would use, but I'm just wondering what exactly you are wrapping. Is the find bringing back any results?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to replace plain URLs with links?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37684/how-to-replace-plain-urls-with-links)

Comment: @DarrenCrabb the find doesn't return anything because I think it's looking for elements with that name, rather than a string search.

Comment: Part of the problem, unless it's just a typo, is that `$.fn.html()` is a method, not a member. Make sure you're calling it with parens at the end. And you're right, `$.fn.find` is in fact a method to search for child elements based on a selector, and what you're passing it probably doesn't even run, since that `://` at the end will invalidate it as a query selector.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to replace it with the RegExp:

```
$('article.tweet').each(function(){
  var linkHref = $(this).html().replace(/http:\/\/\S+/g, function (match) {
     return "<a href='" + match + "'>" + match + "</a>"
  });
  $(this).html(linkHref);
});
```

Provide a function in the second argument of `replace()` to format each matched URL.

[Fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/bD5ky/)

Comment: Perfect thanks! I've not user regular expressions before but this does the job nicely.

Comment: @Coop you are welcome. You can find a better regular expression to match URLs [here](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/10/the-problem-with-urls.html).